# Когда стоит обрабатывать исключительные ситуации и сообщать ли пользователю?

Tags: python, исключения

Когда стоит их обрабатывать? И нужно сообщать пользователю или нет?

```
try:
    res = f(*args,  **kwargs)
except ValueError:
    res = 0
return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Обрабатывать исключения - обязательная практика любого хорошего программиста.

Смотрите, у вас работает программа, а потом срабатывает исключение, и программа больше не работает. Грустно, согласитесь?

И ладно если программу можно легко перезапустить, а если это веб-сервер, который связан с ещё десятью различными приложениями, которые из-за отключения веб-сервера тоже перестанут работать? Перезапускать каждый раз будет неудобно и долго, при этом в момент перезапуска все активные пользователи слетят и не смогут использовать ваш сервис. Да и где гарантия, что такое же не произойдёт через минуту после перезапуска?

Поэтому в момент написания кода вы **обязательно** должны предусмотреть все возможные исключения и своевременно их обработать, чтобы приложение продолжило функционировать.

> И нужно сообщать пользователю или нет?

Всё зависит от специфики приложения и вашей внутренней логики, допустим ваша программа умножает введённое число на два, а на вход подали не число, а строку, тогда логично сообщить пользователю, что стоит указать именно число, а можете ничего не выводить, просто удалять введённый текст и ничего не делать, решать вам в соответствии с тем, что должно делать приложение по вашей задумке.

**Дополнительно**

В питоне все исключения наследуются от базового класса - `BaseException`, он включает в себе абсолютно все исключения, которые могут произойти и нарушить работу программы, но в большинстве случаев достаточно обработать конкретный класс исключения, который от него наследуется и может произойти именно в вашей программе, например `ZeroDivisionError`, для определения действий, которые нужно выполнить при делении на ноль.

Существует так называемая иерархия исключений, каждый класс отвечает за конкретную ситуацию и тип возбуждаемого исключения. Подробнее можете прочитать в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Если вы хотите обработать абсолютно все исключения, то это считается плохой практикой, лучше прописывать конкретные классы исключений, которые могут произойти, а особенно не стоит это делать при помощи `except BaseException:`, поскольку данный класс включает в себя не только программные исключения, но и `SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, GeneratorExit`, ошибки на уровне системы и прерывания работы программы с клавиатуры, которые должны выполняться практически всегда, так как не зависят от логики приложения.

Если и производить обработку всех исключений на уровне программы, то лучше использовать команду `except Exception:`